# How to raise custom error message in Sails.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, sails.js

I am very new to Sails.js (0.9.13) and to node style programming in general. Any help appreciated.  The collowing example is from a UserController:

```
module.exports = {

    save: function (req, res) {

        var u = {    
            firstName: req.param('firstName'),
            lastName: req.param('lastName'),
            email: req.param('email'),
            password: req.param('password'),
        };

        User.create(u).done(function(err,user){
            if(err) {       
                if( err.code == 'ER_DUP_ENTRY' ) {
                    return new Error('Duplicate: email address already in use.','UserController');
                }
                console.log( err );
                return;
            } 
            console.log( user );
        });
   }
}
```

So I am trying to capture the 'ER_DUP_ENTRY' error code and return a custom error message, but I am having no luck as written. How exactly should I be doing this?

Comment: Under what conditions is this code run?  Is it in response to a regular HTML form post, an AJAX POST, an request from an API consumer, or something else?  That will determine the type of response you should send.

Comment: Also, I hope you're not really starting with Sails 0.9.0.  The latest stable release is 0.9.13.  Time for an upgrade!

Comment: @ScottGress Yes, latest Sails 0.9.13.  This is running in th UserController as response to a straight up form post.  My question is really about how to detect and or intercept the create function's ER_DUP_ENTRY so I can package an appropriate reply.  And then, yes the packaging of said response needs to be appropriate to the invokation type.

Comment: @RSAdmin do you know if 'ER_DUP_ENTRY' is accessible in User.findOrCreate() i keep getting a ER_UKNOWN but in further reading its clear its due to a duplicate entry EDIT: Or do i have it all wrong, and the ER_DUP_ENTRY comes from sails-mysql and not sails-memory...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If what you're intending is to return an error to the client, there are several ways to go, but all of them start with the [`res` object](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/master/reference/Response.md) that is passed as an argument to your controller action.  All of the latest builds of Sails have a few basic error responses baked into that object, so you can do (for example):

```
res.serverError(err)
```

instead of `return new Error` to show a general error page with a 500 status code.  For JSON-only API calls that don't expect HTML, it'll send a simple object with the status code and the error.  There's also:

```
res.notFound() // 404 response
res.forbidden() // 403 response
res.badRequest() // 400 response
```

For your "duplicate entry" error, you'll probably want something more customized.  Since your example is coming from a form post, the best practice would be to actually save the error as a flash message and redirect back to the form page, for example:

```
req.flash('error', 'Duplicate email address');
return res.redirect('/theView');
```

and then in your form view, display errors using something like:

```
<% if (req.session.flash && req.session.flash.error) { %><%=req.flash('error')%><% } %>
```

As an alternative, you could just display a custom error view from your controller:

```
return res.view('duplicateEmail');
```

If you're responding to an API call, you'll want to send a status code and (probably) a JSON object:

```
return res.json(409, {error: 'Email address in use'});
```

The point is, rather than returning (or throwing) an `Error` object in your controller code, you want to use the `res` object to respond to the request in some way.

Comment: Precisely the answers I was seeking. Thank you Scott. (One question: is this correct in your example code: `<%=req.flash('error')%>` ? The other reference on the same line looks at the `req.session.flash.error` ...

Comment: Yes--actually calling `req.flash('error')` will retrieve *and clear* the flash message, whereas accessing `req.session.flash.error` just checks whether or not it exists.

Comment: shouldn't it be `return res.json({error: 'Email address in use'}, 409);`?
[The docs](http://sailsjs.org/#!documentation/controllers) specify `res.json(obj[, headers|status[, status]])`

Comment: @ScottGress the given example appears to fail with a `Cannot read property 'error' of undefined` in v0.10.0-rc8. Can you suggest another way to check for error existence? Thanks!

Comment: @dbasch good catch, the example wasn't checking for `req.session.flash` first.  Updated now.  You could avoid this by serving your view from a controller and setting the `flash` local like `res.view({flash: req.flash()})`, then just doing `<% if (flash.error) { %><%=flash.error%><% } %>`, but that's not possible if your route is pointing directly to a view.