# Non existing property: EventEmitter memory error instead of proper error message

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

In a NodeJS 6.10.2/SailsJS 0.12.13 based JavaScript application I experience since several months a strange  error behavior.

In a Sails controller, I try to retrieve a property of a literal object:

```
console.log(someObject.someProperty);
console.log("I am still here!");
```

However, in my case `someObject` is undefined. So, I'd expect to get an error like 'Cannot read property someProperty of undefined.' - and then either Node.js to stop completely or the code to go on (with the next `console.log`).

Instead, the code simply stops executing at that point and I get a strange warning: "(node:4822) Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit." It is however, unpredictable how often this error occurs. Somethings only once, somethings about 20 times right after each other.

What I found out so for is that it is somehow connected to the question whether there was already a response or not. Consider the following:

```
mySailsControllerFunction: function(req, res) {
    console.log(someObject.someProperty);
    console.log("I am still here!");
    res.json({"foo":"dahoo"});
   }
```

This will result in `Sending 500 ("Server Error") response:  ReferenceError: someObject is not defined` - exactly what I expect.

However, now I first send some response and then trying to access my non existing property, turning the code into:

```
mySailsControllerFunction: function(req, res) {
        res.json({"foo":"dahoo"});
        setTimeout(function () {
          console.log("Yeah!");
          console.log(someObject.someProperty);
          console.log("I am still here!");
       },1000);
}
```

then I often get simply nothing: 'Yeah!' displayed, but nothing comes afterwards. The event listener error is sometimes there, sometimes not. Very strange.

Additionally, and strange enough, the problem seems to be somehow connected to the time passed since the start of Sails. I put the code you see above inside a Sails controller function which is called immediately after the clients re-connect. I then played around with the timeout values, restarting the Sails server several times. Outcome: If I set the timeout to 1s, in 4 of 5 tests, I will get the correct error behavior. For 10 seconds it is about 50%, for 30s the error will always be ignored without any console output.

However, if I put my test code outside of the Sails controller, I always get the correct error behavior by Node. So, I'm quite sure this is a wrong behavior of Sails, not Node.

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going on without more context. For instance, if that code is running inside a promise chain, it might be that due to a coding mistake the error gets swallowed. That combined with some strange error handling (_"11 close listeners added"_ seems very weird).

Comment: See my edit above

Comment: what behavior do you observe after you change the eventEmitter limit?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know where to do that exactly. I don't set any event listeners myself here. This is somehow done by Sails.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22579722/6836839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference: I finally solved that issue.
There were, somehow hidden in the code, process exit handlers defined:

```
 process.on('exit', myErrorFunction.bind());
 process.on('SIGINT', myErrorFunction.bind());
 process.on('uncaughtException', myErrorFunction.bind());
```

The problem was: The function in which these lines were in was bound to a cronjob. So, each time the cronjob executed, new handlers were registered. So, my assumption above (before vs. after response) was wrong: In fact everything worked till the cronjob was executed for the first time. From then on, it didn't. And eventually, the warning was fired (correctly!).

I would have never found out without this answer: [Make node show stack trace after EventEmitter warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38482223/make-node-show-stack-trace-after-eventemitter-warning)
You have to add one line of code to get the stack trace:

```
process.on('warning', e => console.warn(e.stack));
```

Additionally, speaking of stack traces: In the Sails serverError response (api/api/responses/serverError.js), it is convenient to access it like this:

```
module.exports = function serverError (data, options) {
  console.log(data.stack);
  /* ... */
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer: I don't know Sails. So it may or may not be related, but my answer may offer a clue.

From the Sails documentation:
http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/response-res/res-json

> This method is terminal, meaning it is generally the last line of code
>   your app should run for a given request (hence the advisory usage of
>   return throughout these docs).

Thus, when you use `res.json({"foo":"dahoo"});`, Sails probably sends the response back to the client, closing the call sequence, which, if it uses Promises or some other async mechanism, may kind of "swallow" further code, as also suggested in an above comment. This is probably internal coding in Sails, so it's not immediately obvious from the outside WHY your second code block specifically doesn't work.

So you should stick to the first pattern: access your property first, and put `res.json()` at the end of the controller function.

Comment: Thanks. However, I'm not convinced. The keyword in the quoted doc snippet is `request`: As far as I understand it, after you're done with the request you can do whatever you want with everything not concerning the request. And if there are no errors, then all my code works as intended. Problem is that errors are not logged/displayed on the console. Furthermore, the strange phenomenon that the problem is somehow connected to server uptime is also not to be explained with the assumption that everything after `res.json` is not executed at all.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. It usually calls for errors - in whatever language - to access properties, data and function threads after you responded to your (http) requestor. Think about it - a http client requests a resource, the backend does some spinning, and returns a response. Conceptually, this closes the loop, the call is considered terminated. I suggest to revisit your code - why do you need to access anything after you responded to the client? If you really need it, you should spawn some async call to process the data but let the client terminate the call ASAP .

Comment: "You can do whatever you want with everything not concerning the request" - well first, if the call is initiated by the client, how can it not be concerning the request. Second, you'll have the client waiting for your backend processes, this is considered anti-pattern. Third, as in the above comment, yes, do whatever you want after the request, but if it's not related to the request, it should indeed leave the request alone - terminate the http response, but process async - decouple your code. But the docs are clear - res.json() should be last in the request.

Comment: options are redis, messaging, micro-services....whatever decouples your backend process from the http call

Comment: last word - you're using a Sails controller. A controller conceptually is part of the MVC pattern to handle a request. With `res.json()` you are saying "I am done with the HTTP request", which runs in the realm of a MVC controller running inside a HTTP context. Thus effectively you are saying I am done, then the framework (Sails) takes over, terminating the call, and then your code pretends to do something else. So in the HTTP context, whatever you do should be before res.json(), and if you need to leave the HTTP context, do it async.

Comment: Thanks for you thoughts! Well, the purpose of doing something after `res.json` is quite common: User A does something, all the other users should be informed via in-app notifications, toastings, even emails and so on (without letting User A wait). That's actually happening in a different function, but the preparation (putting together the information needed) is done in the controllers themselves. I agree that this might not be the best design one could think about.

Comment: However, I still see no general conceptual problem. After `res.json` the client should be "satisfied". As you say, the call is terminated. However, why should the fact that the call is closed and all the HTTP stuff is done prevent the server from going on doing something else? And that works in general. Imagine the following controller content: `res.json({"message":"You got a message!"}); setTimeout(function () { console.log("I do whatever I want"); },5000);` That works perfectly fine for me: The client gets his message immediately and 5 seconds later I get a log on the backend console.

Comment: Your latter example may work, but the docs are clear - it's not guaranteed to work. And in case you're having an error (like in your original question), error handling may cause it to stop working. You should face the fact that you are imposing on Sails something (" I do whatever I want") Sails says it doesn't support ("This method is terminal,...")